# Issue with displaying data in viewflipper from sqlite

Tags: android, sqlite

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [How to display content from sqlite using ViewFlipper in android](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14133943/how-to-display-content-from-sqlite-using-viewflipper-in-android)

I have data from sqlite and i want to display the data one by one as per records in sqlite with the help of viewflipper for that i am using hash map ..To be more clear i am having 2 records in sqlite now i want to display the first record and later 2 by flipping for that i am using

```
    cache = new ArrayList<String>();
    while (cursor.moveToNext())
    {
         String temp_bookid = cursor.getString(0);
         Log.i("temp_bookid",temp_bookid);
         String temp_desc=cursor.getString(1);
         byte[] temp_image1 = cursor.getBlob(2);
         byte[] temp_image2 = cursor.getBlob(3);
         String temp_id=cursor.getString(4);
         String temp_name = cursor.getString(5);
         String temp_bname=cursor.getString(6);
         cache.add(temp_id);
         cache.add(temp_bname);
         cache.add(temp_bookid);
         cache.add(temp_name);
         cache.add(temp_desc);
         cache.add(temp_image1.toString());
         cache.add(temp_image2.toString());
            Log.i("temp_id of the page in sqlite", temp_id);

            TextView txtDesc = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tDescription);
            text = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tTitle);
            text.setText(temp_name);

            txtDesc.setText(temp_desc);

            ImageView img = (ImageView)findViewById(R.id.smallImage);


            img.setImageBitmap(BitmapFactory.decodeByteArray(temp_image1, 0,temp_image1.length));
            txtName1 = (TextView) findViewById(R.id.tvName);
            txtName1.setText(temp_bname);

            break;
    }   

        mContext = this;
        vf = (ViewFlipper) this.findViewById(R.id.vfShow);
        vf.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        @Override
            public boolean onTouch(final View view, final MotionEvent event) {
                detector.onTouchEvent(event);
                Log.i("ew","ae");

                return true;
            }
        });
```

using the above code i can only set first record data since i am using break; statement if i remove break; it is displaying last record..

Comment: first take all values inside ArrayList then override onFling for Changing value of textView one by one

Comment: any tutorial to refer this kind of stuff @prosper k

Comment: see [this](http://blog.kerul.net/2010/11/using-fling-motion-gesture-in-android.html) tutorial may help you more

Comment: @prosper k i have done with viewflipper thing is i cant able to set the data one by one ..